# Cant make ScrollView to work

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

I have this layout that is filled with Edit Text, its purpose is to save the user's inputs, but i have a lot's of them and i want to put more but i just don't have enough space in a 5'' phone to make them all appear, and i need to scroll in order to see the other inputs.At the moment I have this XML but i can't make the `ScrollView` work! And i need to make it work for the entire view. Can you guys help me out and tell me what am I doing wrong ? thanks!

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <RelativeLayout 

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:background="@color/teste"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.luisalmeida.theblackbook.AddHookupActivity$PlaceholderFragment" 

    >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextFrom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewLocation"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTextPlace"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewName"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editTextPlace"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewPlace"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewLocation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textViewObs"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewPlace"
        android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
        android:text="@string/homeHookup"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/teste2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewObs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editTextObs"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewLocation"
        android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
        android:text="@string/obsHookup"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/teste2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewPlace"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editTextFrom"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewAge"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:text="@string/placeHookup"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/teste2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextPlace"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewPlace"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewPlace"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editTextPlace"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewName"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:text="@string/ageHookup"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/teste2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextAge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewAge"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewPlace"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editTextAge"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
        android:text="@string/nameHookup"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/teste2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextObs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewObs"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editTextFrom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="82dp"
        android:ems="10" >

    </EditText>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSave"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textViewPlace"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:text="@string/saveHookup"
        android:onClick="saveHookup" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? "Cannot make it work" tells us nothing about the problem. Stacktrace?

Comment: When i run the APP, the scroll view simply doesnt work, i flip the cell over and the textviews and editviews get over each other and when i try to scroll it, it doesnt give any response its like it isnt even there

Comment: Change RelativeLayout with vertical `LinearLayout`

Comment: but if i do that my alignments are all gone and i have to redo the entire layout

Comment: use `android:layout_alignParentLeft`, 'android:layout_alignParent`Right', `android:layout_below` and etc to align your views inside `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: @velis i just changed to a linear layout and it works just like i wanted! thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad to hear it's working out for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this instead:

```
<ScrollView>
    <TableLayout>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView/>
            <EditText/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView/>
            <EditText/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView/>
            <EditText/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView/>
            <EditText/> 
        </TableRow>
        // Add other EditText and TextView here
   </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

UPDATE 1:

@LuisAlmeida: It doesn't stop you from adding more one components into a `TableRow` so you can get your *Name: "input here"* layout (See my updated layout above). Also, the layout you posted above doesn't give you *Name: "input here"* layout anyway, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: i dont want to add a table because the purpose is too add like a Person's profile, with name etc
like this 
Name: "input here"

Comment: Gonna try the aproach of a Linear Layout first and then if it doenst work i'll give it a shot!

Comment: it does, im placing this like this

TextView EditView;
TextView EditView;
TextView EditView;

Comment: the linearlayout worked just like i wanted! but thanks anyway!